# Is there a unified way to call Invoke() in C#?

Tags: c#, func

The following test passes, but I'm wondering if a unified treatment is possible. Can it be done?

```
public abstract class MyInvokable<TResult> {
  public abstract TResult Invoke();
}
public class IntInvokable: MyInvokable<int> {
  public override int Invoke() {
    return 12;
  }
}
[Test()]
public void FunctionInvokeTest () {
  Func<int> foo = () => 6;
  IntInvokable bar = new IntInvokable();
  int six = foo.Invoke();
  int twelve = bar.Invoke();
  Assert.AreEqual(6, six);
  Assert.AreEqual(12, twelve);
  /* Now, what I really want to do but can't, as far as I can tell:
  List<SomeType> list = new List<SomeType>(){foo, bar};
  Assert.AreEqual(6, list[0].Invoke());
  Assert.AreEqual(12, list[1].Invoke()); */
}
```

EDIT: started a feature request with Microsoft here:
http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/10185579-create-an-iinvokable-t-interface

Comment: I'm fairly certain you can't really get this to work, but explaining *why* is a whole other matter :D

Comment: possibly [`Delegate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate(v=vs.110).aspx) class?

Comment: Why would you use different things? You can store them in a list if they are all the same `type`.

Comment: They might come from different sources, modules, etc. This is the essence of polymorphism.

Comment: Yes, but with polymorphism in object oriented programming you also have some common knowledge. Here the only common knowledge is that somewhere in the object hierarchies (plural) you have an Invoke method, that's not good enough. You need to inherit from a common base, or implement a common interface, and the types involved doesn't do that. To truly have one data structure able to contain these things you would need to wrap the delegate in something, like a class that descends from `MyInvokable<int>`.

Comment: There is no way to define a list that is basically `List<Type that has an Invoke method>` without baking that requirement into an interface or inheriting from a common base class, and thus you need every type involved to actually implement that interface or descend from that type. Since you want to add delegate types, which you cannot change, then this is a no-go. You should look into wrapping the delegate in a class, or wrapping every class in a delegate, that way you would have one common type to store in the list.

Answer (score 2):

C# does not allow anything even remotely close to this type of dynamic behaviour.

But, it you do need to go this route, you can always use `dynamic`, basically signaling the compiler that all bets are off. This would work:

```
 List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>(){foo, bar};
 Assert.AreEqual(6, list[0].Invoke());
 Assert.AreEqual(12, list[1].Invoke());
```

but you cannot guarantee in any way that whatever is in the `list` variable, actually has an `Invoke` method.

The feature most like this one is TypeScript's structural interfaces - as long as a type has all the methods / properties required by the interface, it's considered to implement the interface. 
In C#, the only way that two different things can be considered as having a similar type, is for them to explicitly declare that they implement the same interface, or inherit the same base class.

It would be nice to be able to somehow have a structural semantics in C#, but it's not even on the roadmap, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

To have a `List<T>` where the only requirement you want is that `T` has a parameterless `Invoke` method you need to bake that requirement into either an interface or a base class.

So either of these two would work:

```
public interface IInvokable
{
    int Invoke();
}

var l = new List<IInvokable>();
```

or this:

```
public class Invokable
{
    public virtual int Invoke() { ... }
}

var l = new List<Invokable>();
```

Obviously, now you need to wrap the delegate in that class, for instance like this:

```
public class FuncInvokable : IInvokable
{
    private readonly Func<int> _Func;
    public FuncInvokable(Func<int> func) { _Func = func; }
    public int Invoke() { return _Func(); }
}
```

or... you could just place delegates into the list and wrap all objects in delegates instead:

```
var l = new List<Func<int>>();
l.Add(foo);
l.Add(() => bar.Invoke());
```

but there is no way to define this:

```
var l = new List<Type that has an Invoke method>();
```